# How can i shorten my React Route with map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, import, react-router

What I have

```
import Home from "./components/underpages/Home";
import Kontakt from "./components/underpages/Kontakt";
import FAQ from "./components/underpages/FAQ";

// [...]


<Routes>
        <Route path="/"           element={<Home      />} />
        <Route path="/Kontakt"    element={<Kontakt   />} />
        <Route path="/FAQ"        element={<FAQ       />} />
      </Routes>
```

What I want:

```
{siteList.map((sites) => (
              import {site.Name} from "./components/underpages" + {site.path};
            ))}

// [...]

 {siteList.map((sites) => (
              <Route
              path=   {site.path}
              element={<{site.emelent}  />}
              />
            ))}
```

is there a way something like this, which will work?

I want to shorten my `Routes` and use the `.map`-function. in this way, it doesn't work, but is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply make array

like this :

```
const routes = [
  {
    path:'/',
    element:Home,
  },
  {
    path:'/Kontakt',
    element:Kontakt,
  },
  {
    path:'/FAQ',
    element:FAQ,
  }
]
```

and use it in this way :

```
      <Routes>
        {
          routes.map(({path,element:Component})=>{
            <Route path={path}           element={<Component/>} />
          })
        }
      </Routes>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you could load all the route up into an array and map over them:

```
import Home from "./components/underpages/Home";
import Kontakt from "./components/underpages/Kontakt";
import FAQ from "./components/underpages/FAQ";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    Component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/Kontakt",
    Component: Kontakt,
  },
  {
    path: "/FAQ",
    Component: FAQ,
  },
];

...

<Routes>
  {routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
    <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} />
  ))}
</Routes>
```

A simpler approach is to use a more optimal routes configuration and the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-routes) hook provided by `react-router-dom`.

Example:

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./components/underpages/Home";
import Kontakt from "./components/underpages/Kontakt";
import FAQ from "./components/underpages/FAQ";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: "/Kontakt",
    element: <Kontakt />,
  },
  {
    path: "/FAQ",
    element: <FAQ />,
  },
];

...

const routeElements = useRoutes(routes);

...

return routeElements;
```